# Select All latest Record

Tags: mysql, select

So I have this sample data.

Note that datetime and refreshed date format is date, running time is integer while the others are varchar.
I want to select the records of the latest entry group by applications.

| datetime | Applications | Server | appstatus | refresheddate | runningtime | log |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | A | 1 | 1 | 8/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 60 | 01 |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | B | 1 | 0 | 8/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 60 | 00 |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | C | 1 | 1 | 8/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 60 | 01 |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | A | 2 | 0 | 7/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 150 | 00 |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | B | 1 | 1 | 7/9/2023 7:10:00 AM | 200 | 01 |
| 7/8/2023 10:23:00 | C | 1 | 1 | 1/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 1007 | 00 |
| 6/8/2023 10:23:00 | D | 1 | 1 | 7/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 200 | 01 |
| 6/8/2023 10:23:00 | D | 1 | 0 | 1/9/2023 7:10:00 AM | 100 | 00 |

I need an output like this (latest record from each application):

| datetime | Applications | Server | appstatus | refresheddate | runningtime | log |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | A | 1 | 1 | 8/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 60 | 01 |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | B | 1 | 0 | 8/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 60 | 00 |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | C | 1 | 1 | 8/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 60 | 01 |
| 9/8/2023 11:23:00 | A | 2 | 0 | 7/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 150 | 00 |
| 6/8/2023 10:23:00 | D | 1 | 1 | 7/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 200 | 01 |

this db gets updated every 10 minutes, so i need a query that will show the newest entries group by applications.

Here's the query that i use:

```
SELECT log_history.* FROM log_history,(SELECT MAX(DATETIME) AS DATETIME, applications FROM log_history GROUP BY applications) max_test
    WHERE log_history.datetime = max_test.datetime AND
    log_history.applications = max_test.applications
    ORDER BY SERVER;
```

but somehow, some of the records don't show up. for example, if i use the query above, i got 56 record for the records with server 1, but if use this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT app FROM log_history WHERE SERVER = '1';
```

i got 90 results.

Am i missing something? or there's something wrong with the AND impelemtation? but i don't think that's the case since all of the records for columns datetime and applications are the same every time the db gets updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table containing the data

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM your_table_name t1
JOIN (
    SELECT Applications, MAX(Datetime) AS max_datetime
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY Applications
) t2 ON t1.Applications = t2.Applications AND t1.Datetime = t2.max_datetime;
```

Comment: thank youu! i tried your query while adding a condition where server = 1, it shows 86 records, but when i try 

SELECT DISTINCT applications FROM log_history WHERE SERVER = 1

It shows 96 records.
Is there a reason why it doesn't add up?

Comment: Did you added the condition in sub query as well?

Comment: ahh i see, i tried adding the condition in the subquery and it works. Thank you so much Mr. Nikhil